# Efficient implementation of faceted search in relational databases

Tags: sql, database, database-design, tagging, faceted-search

I am trying to implement a [Faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search) or tagging with multiple-tag filtering. In the faceted navigation, only not-empty categories are displayed and the number of items in the category that are also matching already applied criteria is presented in parenthesis.

[I can get all items having assigned categories using INNER JOINs](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/TagSchema#Items_Having_All_of_A_Set_of_Tags) and [get number of items in all category using COUNT and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653280/getting-count-of-related-tags), however I'm not sure how it will scale to millions of objects and thousands of tags. Especially the counting.

I know that there are some not-relational solutions like [Lucene + SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), but I've found also some closed-source RDBMS-based implementations that are said to be entreprise-strength like [FacetMap.com](http://facetmap.com) or [Endeca](http://www.endeca.com/) software, so there must be an efficient way to perform faceted search in relational databases.

Does anybody have experience in faceted search and could give some tips?

Cache the counts for each category set? Maybe use some smart incremental technique that will update the counters?

Edit:

An example of faceted navigation can be found here: [Flamenco](http://orange.sims.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/flamenco.cgi/famuseum/Flamenco).

Currently I have the standard 3-table scheme (items, tags and items_tags like described here: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html#toxi ) plus a table for facets. Each tag has assigned a facet.

Comment: Do you have tables set up already? Can you provide the structure?

Comment: To clarify, Endeca is not a wrapper on a relational database. It stores all information necessary for faceted search and other operations internally.

Comment: Flamenco link does not work anymore. Is this the new one? http://flamenco.berkeley.edu/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only confirm what Nils says. RDBMS are not good for multi-dimensional searching. I have worked with some smart solutions, caching counters, using triggers, and so on. But in the end, external dedicated indexer always wins.

MAYBE, if you transform your data into dimensional model and feed it to some OLAP [I mean MDX engine] - it will perform well. But it seems a bit too heavy solution, and it will be definitely NOT real-time.

On the contrary, solution with dedicated indexing engine (think Lucene, think [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/)) can be made near-real time with incremental index updates.

Answer (score 7):

Faceted Search is an analytic problem, which means dimensional design is a good bet. Aka, the thing you search against must be in tabular form.

Include all columns of interest in your analytic table.

Put continuous values into buckets.

Use boolean columns for "many" items like categories or tags, example if there are three tags "foo", "bar", and "baz", you would have three boolean columns.

Use a materialized view to create your analytic table.

Index the crap out of it. Some databases support indexes for this type of application.

Only filter once.

Union your results.

Build pre-aggregated materialized views for common queries.

This article might help you too: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/

```
with filtered as (
    select
    *
    from cars_analytic
    where
        [some search conditions]
)

--for each facet:

select
    'brand' as facet,
    brand as value,
    count(*) as count
from
    filtered
group by
    brand

union

select
    'cool-tag' as facet,
    'cool-tag'as value,
    count(*) as count
from
    filtered
where
    cool_tag

union

...


-- sort at the end
order by
    facet,
    count desc,
    value
```

100,000 records with 5 facets in ~ 150 ms

Answer (score 6):

IMO, relational databases aren't that good at searching. You would get better performance from a dedicated search engine (like Solr/Lucene).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the counts, why pull them via SQL? You'll have to iterate through the result set in your code anyway, so why not make your count there?

I'm currently using this approach in a faceted search app I'm developing and it's working fine. The only tricky part is to setup your code to not output the facet until it reaches a new facet. At that time, output the facet and the number of rows you found for it.

This approach assumes you're pulling back a list of all matching items, and thus, multiple rows with the same facet. When you order this result by facet it's easy to get the count in your code instead.

Comment: There can be hundreds of thousands of matching records so I can't store the result set in memory. I'm retrieving only the first page, but I want to know how many records from the entire result set fit into categories displayed under facets.