# website written in asp.net with faceted search

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, solr, lucene, faceted-search

I'm writing a website (using Entity Framework, MySQL, .net 4, C#) which have a lot of categories with subcategories down to 3 levels deep once the user find what he was looking for, each "product" can have different attributes for example:

"Restaurants" can have: average dish price, kids menu available
and
"Gym" can have: swimming pool available, personal trainer available

I'm new to C# and cant figure out how to implement at least simliar to faceted search solution without using library Lucene.NET and search engine Solr, especially that I'll be using probably shared hosting environment.

Wonder if anyone tried to implement similar functionality without using those technologies and have some ideas about db structure and code samples...

Also should I have to use Lucene and Solr does anyone know some cheap VPS hosting which allow installation and usage of Solr, and also might throw some tutorial how to create such faceted search as I couldn't found any.

Thanks

Comment: @Xodarap : no, the OP doesn't want to use Solr or Lucene

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient implementation of faceted search in relational databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847909/efficient-implementation-of-faceted-search-in-relational-databases)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847909/efficient-implementation-of-faceted-search-in-relational-databases), relational databases cannot implement faceting efficiently. Lucene.NET runs in-process so it shouldn't be a problem for a shared hosting environment. Or you could look into some [hosted search solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168634/how-to-evaluate-hosted-full-text-search-solutions).

Comment: we want to know how to implement facet search in c#, not a standard reply that you can't do it "efficiently". Can't you read through the product entries of the relational DB, cache the attributes in memory, than search through this memory array using c# to get the counts for each facet ? quite straight forward in c#, much better than repeating "this question" that it is "impossible" (which is not French).

Answer (score 0):

Subcategories can be implemented to **any** depth efficiently. Implementing a faceted search for `Books`, `Books>Non-Fiction` and `Books>Non-Fiction>Diet` is straightforward: see my question on hierarchical faceting: [Ways to do hierarchial faceting in Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504477/ways-to-do-hierarchial-faceting-in-solr).

---

Dynamic fields are your friend for adding attributes to your entities. Modify schema.xml

```
<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
//you may need a multi-valued string type if you want faceting
```

So you can simply add a document:

```
restaurant_average_dish_price_i: 123
restaurant_kids_menu_available_s:"yes"
```

The first field will be an `int`, ready for comparison operations, the second becomes a string, ready for faceting.

http://www.tnrglobal.com/blog/2010/07/dynamic-fields-in-apache-solr/

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields

---

As for deployment options, please follow Mauricio Scheffer's answer.