# is there an equivalent of the "IN" function for adding "AND"s to queries

Tags: sql-server, tags

i have the following tables in sql server:

**photoalbumsTable:**
album_ID
album_caption

**albumtagmap**
id
album_id
tag_id

**albumtags**
id
tag_name

i have the following query which will show me **where t.tag_name is in "Trips" OR 'Beach":**

```
SELECT b.* FROM albumtagmap bt, photoalbums b, albumtags t
                     WHERE bt.tag_id = t.id
                     AND (t.tag_name IN ('Trips', 'Beach'))
                     AND b.album_id = bt.album_id
                     GROUP BY b.album_id, b.album_caption, b.active, b.description, b.album_name, b.album_date, b.highlight_picture
                     ORDER BY b.album_date desc
```

what is the equivalent query if i want to show **where t.tag_name is in "Trips" AND 'Beach'**
meaning where there are entries in the albumtagmap table for this particular photoalbum for each tag.

Comment: Just wondering, is it really not clear how to select items with multiple tags from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654383/getting-related-tags-from-sql-server-when-you-have-filtered-down/1654407 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( SELECT b.* FROM albumtagmap bt, photoalbums b, albumtags t
WHERE bt.tag_id = t.id
AND t.tag_name='Trips'
AND b.album_id = bt.album_id )

INTERSECT

( SELECT b.* FROM albumtagmap bt, photoalbums b, albumtags t
WHERE bt.tag_id = t.id
AND t.tag_name = 'Beach'
AND b.album_id = bt.album_id )

ORDER BY  album_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you might want to use a JOIN of two subqueries for (one query for each tag, then inner join on album_id). You could also potentially use just an AND of two EXISTS subqueries.